# azure cli trigger failover geo-location cache redis

Tags: azure-cli, azure-redis-cache

I have created two Premium Azure Cache for Redis resources and set up geo replication. There is a button in the portal to failover manually.

How can I trigger this failover with Azure CLI?

I tried the `az redis force-reboot --resource-group $resourceGroupName --name $redisPrimary --reboot-type $rebootType` command to no avail.

Comment: what's the problem with tis command ? could you add the error message please ? Also which version of az cli are you using ?

Comment: @Thomas the command runs fine, the cache is rebooted. But I was hoping that using the force-reboot would trigger a failover to the secondary cache, which is not the case

Comment: have you seen this article ? https://carlos.mendible.com/2021/11/21/azure-cache-for-redis-failover-test/ ? did you have some clients connected to the cache ?

Comment: @Thomas thanks for the article. I figured out in the meantime I will have to use Redis CLI. I will take a look and post results (how-to)

Comment: Awesome, good to hear you re making progress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it in PowerShell by breaking the (geo-replication) link between de caches and then re-creating it, making sure to reverse the primary and secondary cache.

Use the provisioning state to monitor the state after deleting or creating the link:

```
$provisioningState = (Get-AzRedisCache -Name $cacheNamePrimary).ProvisioningState

if ($provisioningState -eq 'Succeeded') { etc.. }
```

One gotcha, after removing the link `Remove-AzRedisCacheLink` and trying to create a new one `New-AzRedisCacheLink`, an error might occur even though the provisioning state will report 'Succeeded'. Error message: `Operation returned an invalid status code 'Conflict'`.

In this case I created a while loop that breaks when the `New-AzRedisCacheLink`  returns no error:

```
# Create cache link (geo-replication)
while ($true) {
    $provisioningState = (Get-AzRedisCache -Name $cacheNamePrimary).ProvisioningState

    if ($provisioningState -eq 'Succeeded') {
        try {
            New-AzRedisCacheLink -PrimaryServerName $cacheNameSecondary -SecondaryServerName $cacheNamePrimary -ErrorAction Stop
            break
        } catch {
            Write-Output "Trying to creating cache link but received an error '$($_)'.. probably busy processing something.. retrying.."
            Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 20000
        }
    } else {
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 30000
        Write-Output "Still waiting for cache link to be removed.. provisioning status '$provisioningState'.."
    }
}
```